# Next.js CPU "electron" high usage

Tags: reactjs, next.js, electron

Hey guys so I'm currently running a Next.js project, but when I `npm run dev` I see "Electron" on my task manager with 100 CPU. Can anyone point me in the right direction on why it's so high? I've disabled JS/TS and other extensions to see if my CPU usage would go down, but it still hasn't. It is pretty frustrating considering I like using Next.js, but the CPU usage is driving me insane. I feel like Next.js is always listening or something, which makes my CPU usage so high. If anyone has some advice I'm willing to listen.

For reference I'm using React 17 and Next 12.